# Observation and Isolated Particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

let's say there is an isolated particle and now I am observing to see whether it is isolated or not. Does this mean that I am interacting with it and breaking its isolation?
Or observing doesn't mean interaction?
BTW these questions are in the context of lagrangian mechanics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Lagrangian mechanics is a formulation of [classical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics). In classical mechanics it is possible to observe an object without disturbing it.

However, in [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) this is not possible. Any observation of one quantum mechanical system by another requires an interaction between the two systems which leaves them [entangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement), so their states are now inter-dependent. In fact, we can no longer properly talk of the state of one system or the other, since entangled systems have a joint state which cannot be split into the product of states of the individual systems.